# How do I make a div show if variable exist in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On login page when a customer wants to purchase wifi service they click on a link http://siteurl/terms.html?premium=show. I need to have the terms page display a hidden division if premium exist and is equal to show without using php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggle(flag)` with true/false for show/hide of the selected element:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$('hiddendivselector').toggle(getParameterByName('premium')=="show")
```

**[Function getparameter refered from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1719752)**